# jQuery .get function(data) not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get

I've placed alert commands in there to ensure the code is being executed. When I run it the first alert message is displayed, but the second never displays. Which leads me to believe the function(data) that returns data isn't being executed.

```
function func(){
    alert("is the function called?");
    $.get("table_snippet.html", function(data){
        alert("test");
        $('#div_id').html(data);
    });

}
```

Comment: check table_snippet.html path

Comment: Something is likely going wrong with the AJAX request, add an error handler to verifyt: `$.get("table_snippet.html", function(data) { alert("test"); }, function(err) { alert(err); })`

Comment: I'd suggest you switch to `$.ajax()` and define an error handler callback.  Then you can log the error and see exactly why the ajax call is failing.  Right now you're just flying blind since you have no way to see what the error is.  You also might look in the debug console to see if any errors are reported.

Comment: @RobM.- where do you see that form of `$.get()` documented (with the third argument for an error handler)?  I don't see it on the jQuery doc page for `.get()`.

Comment: `$.get().fail(function() {alert('error')})`

Comment: Solved: needed to load page through westerner. Hosted through osx terminal